# Classic string manipulation interview questions?

Tags: string

I am scheduled to have an onsite interview so I am preparing few basic questions. According to the company profile, they are big on string manipulation questions. So far I have manually coded these functions:

1. String length, copy, concat, remove white space
2. Reverse
3. Anagrams
4. Palindrome

Can someone give me a list of more classic string questions which I can practice before going there?

Comment: They're publicly stating in their "company profile" that they like to use low-level string manipulation questions in their interviews? That's ... just odd. Good for you to know, I guess, but odd.

Comment: well sorry about that, according to me after studying company profile, i think they are big on string manipulation questions.the company did not provide any information like that

Comment: @user189364: lol save actually saying that they enjoy such questions thoroughly, what exactly about their profile led you to believe that they are "big on string manipulations"? :)

Comment: @incrediman, well i talked to few people that had onsite interview with them, and the feedback according to them (there were two people i talked to) was prepare thoroughly string manipulation

Answer (score 10):

They might ask you about regular expressions. If they are using Java, they might ask the difference of StringBuffer and StringBuilder.

Comment: I agree about the importance of regular expressions for string manipulation.

Comment: if they use low-level string manipulations they would never use regex

Answer (score 5):

Reverse words in a sentence, e.g.

```
"string manip interview question"
```

becomes

```
"question interview manip string"
```

this has a solution that uses only one char worth of temporary space.

Comment: I should have said that you can do this in-place.

Comment: Remember position of the last space char, then shift last word to the left, so that this word will be the first one. Do it for every word.

Comment: put it in a stack and pop with special condition checking ?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your reversal is in-place. You didn't state, so perhaps it already is.

Asking you to re-implementing `strstr()` or `strtok()` might be up their alley too, I guess.

**UPDATE**: As a bonus, if you do end up re-implementing either of those, remember to *not* name your functions starting with `str`, since that namespace is reserved. Having a candidate display that knowledge in an interview would impress me, at least. :)

Answer (score 2):

Fast search like Boyer-Moore and Knuth-Morris-Pratt.  Fast strlen by examining more than one byte at a time.  Simultaneously finding multiple strings in a large body of text with Rabin-Karp.  Finding nearest matches with things like Levenshtein distance.  Regular expressions and how they might implement parts of it.  Various unicode and other multibyte string encodings and how to convert between them.

Answer (score 2):

Design a regular expression library.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://www.codingbat.com/java/String-3) out. Might not fit the description for 'classic', but very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look up string algorithms in a good algorithm book. For example, the Boyer-Moore algorithm, Tries, Suffix Trees, Minimum Edit Distance, stuff like that.